# Static_cast for const casts away qualifiers

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code with following function and new to C++

```
foo(void const *pCluster, const uint32_t fieldNum, __attribute__((unused)) const uint32_t subFieldNum, const int64_t value)
{
    bool status = false;

    mycustomStruct* const pFlmcCtrl = static_cast<mycustomStruct* const>(pMdbCluster);

   // Some Processing
}
```

This gives error error: `static_cast from 'const void *' to 'mycustomStruct* const'  casts away qualifiers`.

Please help me understand the error here. I could not understand

Comment: Which version of C++ is your question about? C++11 or C++14 or C++17?

Comment: Do you know the different between `const int *` and `int * const`?

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1143272/7251286

Comment: If this is c++ your "void" should be written before foo --> void foo (const... because that is the standard.

Answer (score 1):

This

```cpp
T const* p
```

is a pointer to a `const` `T`. This

```cpp
T* const p
```

is a `const` pointer to a `T`. Notice the difference? In the first example, the thing the pointer points to is the thing that is `const`. In the second example, the pointer itself is the thing that is `const`. Attempting to cast a `void const*` to a `mycustomStruct* const` means casting a pointer that points to something that is `const` to a pointer that points to something that is not `const` (just the pointer itself happens to be `const`). Thus, this cast would drop a `const` qualifier, which is not something that `static_cast` can do…

You probably wanted to write

```cpp
const mycustomStruct* pFlmcCtrl = static_cast<const mycustomStruct*>(pMdbCluster);
```